# Flutter Bloc - Populate form fields based on selected dropdown item

Tags: json, flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-textformfield

I'm trying to use flutter bloc to allow a user select an employee name from a dropdown menu and then populate the form fields on the same screen based on the selected employee. These fields could then be edited. I have looked at the flutter todos example which is the closest functionality to what I want to do but its not exactly the same.

Currently I can get the dropdown button to show and select the employee object (JSON) but I cant get the form fields to populate based on this selection. I can access the employee object and its attributes via state but when I supply the variable to the initialValue attribute of a TextFormField it never shows anything even though printing the variable through the console shows its there.

I have been trying to do this with one bloc for the entire screen but I'm wondering now if its only possible to do this functionality with one bloc for the dropdown button and another bloc for the form.

I would Ideally like to stick with one bloc for the entire screen just for simplicity. Any ideas how I can populate the form fields based on the selected object from a dropdown **using bloc state management**

Heres some code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocListener<UpdateEmployeeBloc, UpdateEmployeeState>(
    listener: (context, state){
      if(state.status.isSubmissionFailure){
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
          ..showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Creation Failure')));
      }
    },
    child: Align(
      alignment: const Alignment(0, -1/3),
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 250)),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: _SelectInput()),
            ],
          ),
          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),

          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: _FirstnameInput()),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
              Expanded(child: _LastnameInput()),
            ],
          ),
          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
          Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child:_UsernameInput()),
                const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                Expanded(child:_PasswordInput()),
              ]
          ),
          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
          Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: _EmailInput()),
                const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                Expanded(child: _PhonenumberInput()),
              ]
          ),
          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
          Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: _JobTitleInput()),
                const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                Expanded(child: _RateInput()),
              ]
          ),
          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right:100, ),
            child: _UpdateEmployeeButton(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}


class _SelectInput extends StatelessWidget{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final employee_objects = context.select((UpdateEmployeeBloc bloc) => bloc.state.employees);
  EmployeeModel? selected_employee;

  //context.read<UpdateEmployeeBloc>().add(UpdateEmployeeFormLoaded());

  print("Employee Objects");

  return BlocBuilder<UpdateEmployeeBloc, UpdateEmployeeState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.employees != current.employees,
      builder: (context, state){
        return DropdownButton<EmployeeModel>(
          key: const Key('updateEmployeeForm_selectInput_textfield'),
          hint: Text("Choose an Employee"),
          value: selected_employee,
          items: employee_objects.map<DropdownMenuItem<EmployeeModel>>((EmployeeModel value){
            return DropdownMenuItem<EmployeeModel>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value.fname + " " + value.lname),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (newVal) {
            print("In onChanged method");
            selected_employee = newVal;
            //BlocProvider.of<UpdateEmployeeBloc>(context).add(EmployeeSelected(selected_employee!));
            context.read<UpdateEmployeeBloc>().add(EmployeeSelected(selected_employee!));
            print("After EmployeeSelected Event");
          },
          //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
        );
      }
  );
}
}



class _FirstnameInput extends StatelessWidget{
const _FirstnameInput({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  String? employee = context.select((UpdateEmployeeBloc bloc) => bloc.state.employee?.fname);
  final state = context.watch<UpdateEmployeeBloc>().state;
  print("FirstnameInput has been built");
  print(state.employee?.fname);

  return BlocBuilder<UpdateEmployeeBloc, UpdateEmployeeState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.fname != current.fname,
      builder: (context, state){
        return TextFormField(
          key: const Key('createEmployeeForm_firstnameInput_textfield'),
          initialValue: employee,
          //initialValue: state.employee?.fname,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
          onChanged: (fname) => context.read<UpdateEmployeeBloc>().add(FirstnameChanged(fname)),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Firstname',
            errorText: state.fname.invalid ? 'Firstname is invalid' : null,
          ),
        );
      }
  );
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal code to get any help. Atleast try to get a single page application with dropdown and form field. This way you'll have a much higher chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @MohitSingh I have added some code. In the _FirstnameInput class I can not get the initialValue to display the value of employee. The employee value is set when a selection is made in the _SelectInput class and event is generated and a new state is emitted but the UI doesnt show the change in _FirstnameInput

Comment: you're not actually showing the text in TextFormField at all. Create a TextEditingController, add it to the controller property of TextFormField and update its text in the builder function whenever a new state is detected.

Comment: @MohitSingh. Thanks for the response. I dont understand why I need to use a TextEditingController as opposed to giving InitialValue a variable from state like I have done above. Could you explain this? I know the value of the employee variable in _FirstnameInput contains a value as I can print it on the console.

Comment: @MohitSingh Also further to my previous comment if you look at the official Flutter todos example, more specifically the edit todos page here https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial?id=edittodopage you will see that he is able to set the initial value without having to use a TextEditingController, he just passes the variable from state which is what I am trying to do also

Comment: In the attached example, initialTodo is just an argument for EditTodoBloc which is a custom class created by the user however in TextFormField, initialValue is an argument that just shows an initial value in the form field and does not keep track of changing data. In short, in docs, it is a custom argument and implementation is different than that in TextFormField.

Comment: @MohitSingh Ah I think I understand now. So a text editing controller is the only way I can update the initialValue property when data can change? Maybe using block consumer and listening for a specific event/state change would work in my initial example.